# check if record exists in table pyramid-SQLalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I developed application using pyramid SQLalchemy with postgres relational database. I would like to check whether row is in table or not. So I tried the following steps

```
def nextPage(request):
  query = request.dbsession.query(NewEntry)
  msheet_no = request.params['msheet_no']
  obj1=NewEntry()
  getRoll=query.filter(NewEntry.batch==batch).order_by(-NewEntry.roll_no).first() 
  rollno=getRoll.roll_no+1
  obj1.roll_no = rollno
  if(obj1.msheet_no==msheet_no):
     print("Marksheet No is already existed",obj1.msheet_no,'-',msheet_no)
  else:
     request.dbsession.add(obj1)
```

In this code, duplicate `msheet_no` are inserted in table. How to avoid duplicate `msheet_no` are inserted into the table?

Note: `msheet_no` and `rollno` are primary keys in table

Answer (score 1):

`if(obj1.msheet_no==msheet_no):` In this piece of code you are checking the field value of msheet_no of newly created object which will always be None and hence logically doesn't make sense. Two suggestions here :

1. Either get all the values of existing `msheet_no` from the db and insert only if it is not present.
2. Query using intersection using `except_` to return those values which are yet to be inserted.

I think in your scenerio you have to go with the first lookup kind of thing. Only downside is that you will need to query each time you intent to insert a new object.